# How can I filter specific emails from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get from an array of multiple emails string this effect
if there is more than one email that ends with the same domain name of the email do not show me that filter for example:

const db = ['example@example.com', 'example2@example.com'];

const check = ['example3@example.com', 'another@anotherdomain.com'];

function findNotSimilar(check, db) {

```
const arr = check.filter((item) => db.indexOf(item) === -1);
return arr;
```

}

this returns ['example3@example.com', 'another@anotherdomain.com'], but I would like to return just  ['another@anotherdomain.com'] array because the email ending with the same domain name

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already, have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: There are literally [**hundreds** of previous questions on this topic](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+filter+array+other+array). Please [search thoroughly](/help/searching) before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. But regarding the domains.. you have to consider domains with 2 parts like '.co.uk' in comparison with simple '.com'.

```
function Test() {
    const db = ['example@example.com', 'example2@example.com'];
    const check = ['example3@example.eu', 'another@anotherdomain.com'];
    const dbFiltered = db.map(x => x.split('@')[1].split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')).filter((x, y, z) => z.indexOf(x) === y);
    const arr = check.filter((item) => dbFiltered.map(x => item.indexOf(x) === -1).every(x => x === true));
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working Demo :**

```js
const db = ['example@example.com', 'example2@example.com'];
const check = ['example3@example.com', 'another@anotherdomain.com'];

// Split the array elements with domain name and creating a new array.
const formatDb = db.map((item) => item.split('@')[1]);

// Filtered out the element with different domain name.
const arr = check.filter((item) => formatDb.indexOf(item.split('@')[1]) === -1);

console.log(arr);
```